# Sort array and add new properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make `array2` look like the `array1` sequence. If any property is missing I would like to add that property to `array2` and give a value of `0`.

```js
Array1 = ["BREAKFAST", "AM", "LUNCH", "PM", "DINNER"]
Array2 = [
  {
    daypart: "DINNER",
    time: 10,
  },
  {
    daypart: "PM",
    time: 15,
  },
  {
    daypart: "LUNCH",
    time: 9,
  },
]

expectedArray = [
  { daypart: "BREAKFAST", time: 0 },
  { daypart: "AM", time: 0 },
  { daypart: "LUNCH", time: 9 },
  { daypart: "PM", time: 15 },
  { daypart: "DINNER", time: 10 },
]
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sffddu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
const Array1 = ['BREAKFAST', 'AM', 'LUNCH', 'PM', 'DINNER'];
const Array2 = [
    {
        daypart: 'DINNER',
        time: 10
    },
    {
        daypart: 'PM',
        time: 15
    },
    {
        daypart: 'LUNCH',
        time: 9
    }
];

const result = Array1.map(daypart => 
    ({ daypart, time: 0, ...Array2.find(e => e.daypart === daypart) })
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#map` along with `Array#find`.

```js
const Array1 = ['BREAKFAST', 'AM', 'LUNCH', 'PM', 'DINNER'],
Array2 = [{
          daypart: 'DINNER',
          time: 10
          },
          {
          daypart: 'PM',
          time: 15
          }, {
          daypart: 'LUNCH',
          time: 9
          }];
const res = Array1.map(x => Array2.find(({daypart})=>daypart===x) 
   ?? {daypart: x, time: 0});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: for me this answer is bad, the result contains Array2 references and not copies

Comment: @MisterJojo Did the question ever specify that a copy is needed?

Comment: @MisterJojo There's no need to consider it unless one has reason to believe it is necessary. Of course, there's nothing wrong with doing it (in most cases), but it may be superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

I propose...

```js
const
  Array1 = ['BREAKFAST', 'AM', 'LUNCH', 'PM', 'DINNER'],
  Array2 = 
      [ { daypart: 'DINNER', time: 10 } 
      , { daypart: 'PM',     time: 15 } 
      , { daypart: 'LUNCH',  time:  9 } 
      ],
  expectedArray = Array1.map(daypart=>
      {
      let a2el = Array2.find(x=>x.daypart===daypart)
      if (!a2el) return {daypart, time: 0}
      else return {...a2el} // to make a copy
      })


expectedArray.forEach(Ae=>console.log( JSON.stringify(Ae)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```